# Why and When the pg_stat_activity's most of the columns are null?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, amazon-rds-aurora

Recently, I have noticed that when I query the `pg_stat_activity` for few users most of the columns are `[null]` (pgAdmin 4) in the result.

Only thing I can see is `datid, datname, pid, usesysid, usename, application_name, query`, rest all are `[null]`.

There is an interesting part here. When I execute

```
select * from pg_stat_activity where query = '<insufficient privilege>'
```

is returning same rows as

```
select * from pg_stat_activity where state is null
```

and same as

```
select * from pg_stat_activity where client_addr is not null
```

What could be the reason for this?

(I am using RDS Aurora Postgresql 9.6.12)

Answer (score 1):

That must be because you don't have permission to see these user's activities.

Statements can contain sensitive data, so they are only visible to superusers by default.

Some rows in `pg_stat_activity` also contain many NULLs because they belong to background processes.

Comment: Since its RDS, I can't be completely superuser. However, I do have all other privileges (almost everything other than rdsadmin privilege) than other users. I could see there are some read-only user (they do have only basic privileges) rows are having ```NULL``` values. BTW, I have created those users.

Comment: The fact that you created those roles wouldn't make a difference.